# Re-define list within list-comprehension - Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

I'm writing some code where I defined a couple of functions already.
All of these functions take a list as input, and then return a mutated list. Then one final function that uses list-comprehension to do these mutations an x amount of time.

When it has finished 1 'loop', the functions should use the mutated list as input, however, I seem to be unable to find a way to do this. It keeps on looping over the same list, resulting in the wrong output. When it has done all of these mutations it should print a list of the length of all the created lists.

I have made a solution to this problem without list comprehension. It works, but I would like to be able to do this with comprehensions.

note: kills & reproduce are the predefined functions that take some parameters

#### Function + arguments:

```
def simulate(viruses, mortalityProb, mutationProb, maxReproductionProb, maxPopulation, timesteps = 500):
```

#### Code that works:

```
population = [len(viruses)]
for step in range(timesteps):
   viruses = reproduce(kill(viruses, mortalityProb), mutationProb, reproductionProbability(viruses, maxReproductionProb, maxPopulation))
   population.append(len(viruses))
return population
```

#### Code that doesn't work:

```
return [len(virus) for virus in [reproduce(kill(viruses, mortalityProb), mutationProb, reproductionProbability(viruses, maxReproductionProb, maxPopulation)) for step in range(timesteps)]]
```

The working code mutates the viruses list, and in the next run uses the mutated list. In the other piece of code, it uses the same viruses list over and over

Comment: A small reproducible example would be fine, but shouldn't it be `return [len(virus) for step in range(timesteps) for virus in [reproduce(kill(viruses, mortalityProb), mutationProb, reproductionProbability(viruses, maxReproductionProb, maxPopulation))]]`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the list comprehensions properly. Below code snippet will return the list of length of viruses generated from reproduce method for given timestamps

```
return [len([virus for virus in reproduce(kill(viruses, mortalityProb), mutationProb, reproductionProbability(viruses, maxReproductionProb, maxPopulation))]) for step in range(timesteps)]
```

O/P will look like `[3,4,5]`